# Am I using callable and futures multithreading the right way (java)?

Tags: java, multithreading

I need some tasks to be done multi threaded.
I know in advance that i will continue with my program when all tasks are completed.
Is the following code right for this purpose?

```
  public void test() {
    Callable<String> myCall = new Callable() {

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return doDomething();
        }
    };


    Callable<String> myCall2 = new Callable() {

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return doDomething2();
        }
    };

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    List<Callable<String>> list = Arrays.asList(myCall,myCall2);
    List<Future<String>> futuresList = executor.invokeAll(list);

    String result1 = futuresList.get(0).get();

    String result2 = futuresList.get(0).get();

    //...
}
```

---

I'm trying to change this to work with generics:

```
public void test() {
Callable<?> myCall = new Callable() {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return doDomething();
    }
};


Callable<?> myCall2 = new Callable() {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return doDomething2();
    }
};

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
List<Callable<?>> list = Arrays.asList(myCall,myCall2);
List<Future<?>> futuresList = executor.invokeAll((Collection<? extends Callable<?>>)list);

String result1 = futuresList.get(0).get();

String result2 = futuresList.get(0).get();

// ...
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

> The method `invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>>)` in the type ExecutorService is not applicable for the arguments `(Collection<capture#2-of ? extends Callable<?>>)`.

Comment: it looks ok, do you have any problems with running that code?

Comment: no, but i was wondering if there was another implementation that would do the same. How can i implement this without using executor service, for example?

Comment: Why would you want to do it without using an `ExecutorService`? You _could_ accomplish what you want with raw `Thread`s, but the executor framework exists so you don't have to deal with the complexity of that.

Comment: ok. now i'm trying to change the implementation to generic. i change all callable<String> to Callable<?>, but i get a compilation error on executor.invokeAll((Collection<? extends Callable<?>>)list); - The method invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>>) in the type ExecutorService is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<capture#2-of ? extends Callable<?>>). any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from you accessing the zeroth index twice I dont see anything wrong with it.

This edit is in regards to your question on how to implement it without the ExecutorService.  As ColinD notes, you really *shouldn't*  I will show why

To get the same set of functionality you would need two Objects and use two threads as a latch

```
String result1 = null;

String result2 = null;

public void test() {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            result1 = doSomething();
        }
    });
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            result2 = doSomething2();
        }
    });
    thread1.start(); 
    thread2.start();
    thread1.join(); 
    thread2.join();
    ...
    ...

}
```

Now what if you want to add another thread/unit-of-work then you need

```
Thread thread3 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                result3 = doSomething3();
            }
        });
thread3.start();
thread3.join();
```

And so forth.  Hence your solution is the better way to do this.

Comment: thank for the details answer. do you know why what i wrote in the comment above doesnt compile?

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me be devil's advocate then.
The only thing in this example that actually can hit right back at you is the fact that you are calling two methods a-sychronously which is probably not that obvious to other programmers.

I guess this is just an example, but other programmers might not recognize that `doSomething` and `doSomething2` should not have 'shared mutable state' since they are executed a-synchronously. It's not that obvious in this setup.

So I would recommend to actually put the logic in separate classes.